DeferredResult is not setting the result again if we set it initially
I have a requirement where I want to send a status= "in-progress" immediately when I get a request and then call another API to get the response this takes around a minute to return the result. I am using AWS API Gateway which has 30 seconds hard timeout. So I want to poll the results from front end application by calling the API every 10 seconds until we get the response from the API. My below code work asynchronously and fetch the records but it never set the response in the deferredResult. So even after we got the response from the third party API the asynchronously call keep going because we set 10 iteration from front end before we show timeout from the front end.
Please correct me where I am going wrong.
@EnableAsync
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

  private final ThridPartyApi thridPartyApi;
  private MyRequest asyncRequest;

 
  @PostMapping("/big-data")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public DeferredResult<AsyncApiResponse<MyResponse>> getBigData(@RequestBody MyRequest request) {

    if (asyncRequest == null) {
      asyncRequest = request;
    }
    DeferredResult<AsyncApiResponse<MyResponse>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(80000L);
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes);
      try {
        return thridPartyApi.getBigData(request);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }).thenAccept(response -> {
      if (!deferredResult.isSetOrExpired()) {
        deferredResult.setResult(AsyncApiResponse.createCompleted(response));
      }
    }).exceptionally(ex -> {
      if (!deferredResult.isSetOrExpired()) {
        deferredResult.setErrorResult(AsyncApiResponse.createCompleted(null));
      }
      return null;
    });

    if (!deferredResult.hasResult()) {
      log.debug("Request processing is in progress >>>>>");
      DeferredResult<AsyncApiResponse<MyResponse>> dr = new DeferredResult<>();
      dr.setResult(AsyncApiResponse.createInProgress());
      return dr;
    }

    log.debug("Request processing is done");
    return deferredResult;
  }

}

I am calling the POST /api/big-data multiple times in a loop of 10. I am getting "in-progress" response right after the call. But never get the response even all the calls(count 10) exhausted.
Looks like  deferredResult.setResult(AsyncApiResponse.createCompleted(response)) set the result but when it comes to line if (!deferredResult.hasResult()) I see it deferredResult is not set.
I am expecting that I found it set and hence if (!deferredResult.hasResult()) evaluated as false and return deferredResult; gets called with the set value.

By using the Spring DeferredResult, the HTTP connection will remain open until the result is available. However, as the processing will take around a minute and the API gateway has a 30 seconds timeout, the connection will be closed before the result could be returned.
One potential solution is to use a polling API endpoint. When the API request is made to the long processing /big-data API, a request record with status is stored in the database, upon completion of calling the third party API, the data is stored in the database with the status marked as completed. The frontend could do polling on another status API to check for status. As the data is big, there could be another API endpoint with pagination for getting the data.
Another possible solution is to use server sent events to notify the front endpoint upon the processing completion. In this way, polling could be avoided, and then frontend could query the result upon the notification.
